# How to filter a web page by form submission or link click and refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, server-side

My template:

```
<h3> artworks </h3>

<form action="/" method="get">
    <label for="filter">Filter by a tag: </label>
    <input id="tag" type="text" name="name_field">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<ul class="artwork">
  {{#each artwork}}
    <li>
      <h4>{{this.date}} {{this.title}}</h4>
      <pre>
        {{this.ascii}}
      </pre>
      tags: 
      {{#each this.tags}}
    <a href="/?name_field={{{this}}}">{{{this}}}</a>          
  {{/each}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The accompanying Get method in my server side code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.name_field);
  if (req.params.name_field !== undefined) {
    const b = a.filter(art => art.tags.includes(req.params.name_field));
    res.render('mytemp', {artwork: b.reverse()});
  }
  else {
    res.render('mytemp', {artwork: a.reverse()});
  }
});
```

(a is an array of objects that is iterated through and printed in my template)

Essentially, if I type in the form a tag, and click submit, it would reload the page and only show list items who's "tags" element contains whatever was submitted in the form. And additionally, if I click on one of the tags, which are anchor links, it would refresh the page and only show me list items which contain that tag. I'm not sure how I would combine the server side code along with the templating to implement this.

Comment: Your `href` attributes should include query parameters that reflect the tag: `href="/blahblah?name_field=myFavTag"`.  Then (the structure of) your form submit (GET) will be the same as the anchor tag redirects.

Comment: So I would have to edit the anchor tag to something like this:

<a href="/?name=myFavTag">{{{this}}}</a>

The field in the name query should be whatever this is. So how could I do that?

Comment: `<a href="/?name_field={{{this}}}">{{{this}}}</a>`. Note the use of `name_field` rather than `name`.

Comment: So would I modify my Get request or do I have to write a new one? And how would that request path be structured? app.get('/', (req, res) => {stuff });, what is the path I'm entering?

Comment: EDIT: Your route code will need to filter the artwork based upon the tags that are present in the name_field attribute sent from the browser.

Comment: So in my route code, how do I access the name_field attribute sent from the browser?

Comment: You said this: _Essentially, if I type in the form a tag, and click submit, it would reload the page and only show list items who's "tags" element contains whatever was submitted in the form._ about the form. Then you said this: _if I click on one of the tags, which are anchor links, it would refresh the page and only show me list items which contain that tag_. You have everything you need to both of these with the exception of doing the work to (in YOUR words): _only show me list items which contain that tag_. That. happens in your route code.

Comment: Right I came up with the code to filter the array:   

const b = a.filter(art => art.tags.includes( ));
res.render('mytemp', {artwork: b.reverse()});

However, what am I putting in that includes argument so I can filter out the list items?

Comment: Great work. Use the Request object passed in to the router method (`req`) to gain access to the 'name_field' property. `req.params.name_field`. https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req

Comment: Do you know why it's telling me that the name_field param is undefined when I log it? Even though it is evidently going to a url containing that name_field

Comment: Nope. Not without seeing the code.

Comment: Edited the post with updated code

Comment: Yep - because I'm an idiot sometimes :-) - change `params` to `query`.  Sorry <sheepish grin>

Comment: Ah no worries - works perfectly now thank you